# Can NInject load modules/assemblies on demand?

Tags: assemblies, inversion-of-control, ninject

Are there facilities in NInject that will allow me to load services from other modules (assemblies) on demand like it's done in Unity?

Comment: I think I don't understand what do you mean. How do you "load services from other assemblies" in Unity?

Answer (score 13):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Load( Assembly.Load("yourpath_to_assembly.dll");
```

If you look at KernelBase with reflector in Ninject.dll you will see that this call will recursively load all modules in the loaded assemblies (Load method takes an IEnumerable)

```
public void Load(IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)
{
    foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
    {
        this.Load(assembly.GetNinjectModules());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "Like Unity" but you can do a few different things for loading assemblies. Ninject itself will load local assemblies for extensions/plugins by default. Ninject can also load NinjectModule classes from assemblies. If you want to do something more complex, you can use the [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions) project to do a lot of different scanning and type binding.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on how to make Ninject "load NinjectModule classes from assemblies"?
Ninject's wiki covers pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Ok, I got it now, I mixed Ninject versions in my project.

Comment: The provided link to GitHub is broken. Actual link is https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.

Comment: @realsonic Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to loading Assemblies non-statically out of the box, no it doesnt.

There are many other questions on this, e.g., [Using Ninject in a plugin like architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330927/using-ninject-in-a-plugin-like-architecture)