# Resolve all dependencies of the project in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to resolve all the dependencies in my project. My project consists of 3 layers which are Web, Service, and DataAccess.

I have done this before while using AutoFac:

```
var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("OrderForm")).ToArray();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerRequest();
```

Now I want to do the same thing in .net core. I have tried this:

```
var allProviderTypes = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.Contains("Providers"));
```

The problem is that this only returns the web-assembly and not the other ones.

Comment: You can still use AutoFac with (ASP).NET Core's IServiceCollection/IServiceProvider. The .NET Core DI/IoC Container is meant to be simple and lacks the more advanced features. Its a good start and ASP.NET Core was designed to be extensible, including plugging-in of 3rd party IoC container: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html

Comment: @Tseng: But how do I get all the assemblies then? I can't use BuildManager in .net core?

Comment: It should work if it uses `.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()` or `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` (see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/919#issuecomment-270516752)) which is available in the newer .NET Core/Standard versions

Comment: Are you sure about _t.Namespace.Contains("Providers")_ ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Startup.cs in ConfigureServices method

```
  var container = new ContainerBuilder();
        container.Populate(services);

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container.Build());
```

Comment: My senior wrote in our project, so he can explain. But it is working fine. You can use it.

Comment: rofl. It's creating the AutoFac container inside ConfiugreServices and Wraps it around an implementation of `IServiceProvider`, which is then returned from `ConfigureServices` method. ASP.NET Core then uses this provider instead of creating one itself (which would be the default .NET Core IoC container (aka `ServiceProvider`)

Comment: @Bryan Not by default, you still have to use the autoscanning features of autofac to do so. Only classes which are explicitly registered (via methods or assembly scan) are registered and can be resolved. `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` should give you all the loaded assemblies (only .NET Core 2.0 and later)

Comment: @WaqasDilawarDaha: With the above code, only the one registered in `services` (via the `.AddXxx` methods in `ConfigureServices`

Comment: @Tseng alright dear, I have started exploring AutoFac myself.