# Caliburn.Micro HelloScreens sample - using Ninject as IOC container

Tags: ninject, mef, caliburn.micro

Love the Caliburn.Micro HelloScreens example, but am getting stuck with MEFs Dependency Injection. I would prefer to use Ninject as I am most familiar with it. Have read some great articles on hosting MEF in an IOC container (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nblumhardt/archive/2009/03/16/hosting-mef-extensions-in-an-ioc-container.aspx)...but cannot get a simple example working with caliburn.micro.

What I'm looking for is a way to use Ninject Constructor Injection along side MEF. MEF for extension management. Ninject for constructor dependency injection.

I'm looking for a working Caliburn.Micro bootstrapper that incorporates MEF and Ninject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking for a working Caliburn.Micro bootstrapper that incorporates MEF and Ninject?

I have been using Caliburn.Micro for a long time now and I have came across every sample on the internet that uses it, and there is no such sample.

Now I will recommend another thing, using two containers in your application at the same time is pretty tricky as pointed to by the article as well.

So if I were you I would either use MEF which handles a lot of dependency injection tasks although it is not a DI container and of course it supports extension.

On the other hand, if you really like Ninject and use it a lot then you should take advantage of Ninject features, two which are very good for supporting extensions or add-ins which are Conventions Extension or Ninject Modules, you can read more about those two features in this **[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/330927/439667)**.

Comment: I posted out of desperation because I could not figure out how to register an NHibernate ISessionFactory. As always, after I post a question I make progress. As you recommended, I am going to use MEF DI and become proficient at it.

Comment: @faldeland Yes I would recommend that, MEF is a great Extensibility framework, but always remember it is not a full fledged DI container although Microsoft has promised to push in that direction.

Comment: @Sniffer: since you said you have a good experience with Caliburn.Micro, do you know any WORKING example that show how to bootstrap Autofac using CM.Micro? Because I have [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056673/caliburn-micro-autofac-bootstrapping)

Comment: @Daedalus As you can see I am the same guy who commented on the other question, check the codeplex site because I remember I saw something there about use Caliburn.Micro with Autofac. Anyway I think your problem is caused by the presence of multiple assembiles. First try to create a test application with one assembly using Autofac and then try to move on.

Comment: hahahah it's late here and I didn't notice that. Anyway that's what I'm doing, I tried to ask here too =) I'll update the other question, thank you again!