# Caliburn.Micro + Autofac bootstrapping

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, autofac, caliburn.micro

I have a project with Caliburn.Micro, and I'm trying to port from its [`SimpleContainer`](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Simple%20IoC%20Container&referringTitle=Documentation) to [Autofac](http://autofac.org/).

I'm using [this code](https://gist.github.com/kavand/6272568), that is an updated version of the code in [this guide](http://buksbaum.us/2011/06/12/introducing-caliburn-micro-autofac/).
Using `SimpleContainer` I simply did (inside the bootstrapper)

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
{
    this.DisplayRootViewFor<IScreen>(); // where ShellViewModel : Screen
}
```

Now this doesn't work anymore, so what should I do to integrate Autofac with Caliburn.Micro ?

Comment: What is happening, are you getting an exception or what ? Please provide more detail. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing. And the strange thing I ust noticed is that it doesnt even fire the OnStartup method. In theory the DisplayRootViewFor<> should call the WindowManager.ShowDialog for the ShellView with ShellViewModel, but nothing is shown.

Comment: Are you using the Bootstrapper from the link you posted as is with no modification ?

Comment: yes, the one from github. I just added the onstartup override like I was doing when using SimpleContainer

Comment: the only other thing I did is create a plain public class AppBootstrapper : AutofacBootstrapper<ShellViewModel> { }, and in App.cs I only do var boot = new AppBootstrapper(); boot.Start();

Comment: This should be all you need, you don't need to override `OnStartup()`.

Comment: ok but my ShellView won't be displayed, what do I have to do? Is there something I should know?

Comment: oh, one thing I didn't say, all this is done in the App project, Views and ViewModels are in assemblies with the relative name

Comment: That changes things, Aren't you getting a window telling you that it can't find the view ?

Comment: no, the application just starts and nothing happens

Comment: The best thing to do now is Google on how to activate logging in Caliburn.Micro and take a look at the log file so you can diagnose your problem.

Comment: You are welcome, sorry that is all I can help you with so far.

Comment: i tried to add the logging fuctionality, but no error is shown, so I leave here the [download link to the solution I'm using](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7z38wcl26b9gwa/AutofacTests.rar), while I keep trying to get out of it

Comment: Sorry I can't open your solution because I have Visual Studio 2010 while your solution uses a more recent version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your solution.

Firstly, nothing invokes your `AppBootstrapper`. This is normally done in Caliburn.Micro by adding your bootstrapper type as a resource in `App.xaml`. See [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration,%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation) for the instructions for WPF.

i.e. your `App.xaml` should look like this:

```
<Application x:Class="AutofacTests.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AutofacTests">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Secondly, as your view models and views are in different assemblies, both Caliburn.Micro and Autofac will need to know where they are located (for view location and dependency resolution respectively).

The Autofac bootstrapper you are using resolves dependencies from the `AssemblySource` instance that Caliburn.Micro uses for view location. Therefore, you just need to populate this assembly source collection. You do this by overridding `SelectAssemblies` in your `AppBootstrapper`:

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
{
    return new[]
               {
                   GetType().Assembly, 
                   typeof(ShellViewModel).Assembly, 
                   typeof(ShellView).Assembly
               };
}
```

Comment: as I wrote and as you can see in the attached solution, I create a new bootstrapper and call start on it in the app.cs, anyway now I will try your suggestions

Comment: I overrode the SelectAssemblies method but nothing changed, can you please take a look at my solution and tell me the exact edits it needs? thank you

Comment: Those are the exact changes you need, I made them myself to your solution. Have you made the App.xaml change? Is your SelectAssemblies in AppBootstrapper?

Comment: now I created another project putting bootstrapper, view and viewmodel all in the same assembly, and I got it working
now I'll try to separate things, let's see

Comment: I got it working! I can't understand why, but I still get a strange error on the App.xaml bootstrapper resource definition saying that it was unable to find System.Core version 2.0.5.0, but except for that, it works! thank you guys!

Comment: one last thing: what's the difference between instantiating the bootstrapper in the XAML and in application OnStartup? Using SimpleContainer I did it via code and I've never had any problem. Also, I can't just put the resource directly in a resource dictionary, I must create a mergeddictionary, why?